# How to find out when a CloudKit Subscription is deleted?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, cloudkit

I am using CloudKit in my iOS application.

In my application, whenever user modifies some data, I update the CloudKit private db so that other devices of the user can also get updated.

This syncing mechanism can be enabled/disabled by the user.

When user enables syncing, I create a subscription and push the local data to CloudKit.

If the user has logged on to other devices, they start getting remote notifications about changes to the private database as expected.

The application shows a `UISwitch` for the user to enable/disable syncing.

Let us assume the user has 2 devices `DeviceA` and `DeviceB` which show that syncing has been enabled by setting `UISwitch.isOn` to true.

If the user disables syncing on `DeviceA`, then the subscription is deleted and changes made on `DeviceA` do not trigger remote notifications to `DeviceB` as expected.

But `DeviceB` still shows that syncing has been enabled.

Is there a way to know when a subscription has been deleted?

I know about [`CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckfetchsubscriptionsoperation). I can call the `CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation` periodically to know about the subscriptions. Is there a better way to this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **great** question and is something I ran in to as well. You are correct. The only way to know the status of a subscription is to query for what's available with `CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation`.

One possible workaround is to create a `recordType` called something like `Subscription` and save the `subscriptionID`s the user is currently using as **regular CloudKit records** (just use a `String` property on a `CKRecord`).

Then when they unsubscribe on a device, you can update the `Subscription` record and all their devices will get notified of the change. The app would then update the *actual* subscriptions based on the `subscriptionID`s the user has available.

So here's a potential workflow:

1. `DeviceA` unsubscribes from `subscription1`.
2. `DeviceA` deletes `subscriptionRecord1` from the `Subscription` table.
3. `DeviceA` deletes the actual `subscription1` subscription using `CKModifySubscriptionsOperation()`.
4. `DeviceB` gets notified that `subscriptionRecord1` was deleted and flips the sync `UISwitch` to off (I presume you are saving the state of these switches with a local persistence method like a database or `UserDefaults`).

Hopefully that helps. Let me know if you have any questions.